# Facebook graph api page_fans shows different amount of likes than 'likes' chart in admin section / insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I have a page with 31 likes, created 2 days ago. When looking insights in admin section, chart shows proper amount of likes (29 day ago, 31 today), but when fetching data via graph API, 'page_fan_adds/day' and 'page_fan_adds_unique/day' shows "value": 0 for last 30 days.

IS this related to the 48hrs needed to process the data? But then, why correct amount of likes  is visible in admin section of the page?

screenshot of the chart: http://d.pr/i/aUvw

data returned via graph API: http://d.pr/n/XWyr

Answer (score 0):

Insights are not recorded for pages with less then 30 likes. Could be that only total page likes count is recorded so that graph shows data.